# Построение полиз и параллельно выполняемых операций

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1) Ввожу полиз.

2) На выходе получаю обратную польскую запись. ( Хранится в переменной outstring). Вот её мне и надо обработать, как здесь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делаю с помощью функции "oper" в конце main.
Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Не знаю как добавить сюда нормально код, скину в лс. Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Чтобы нормально вставить код добавьте перед началом и концом участка кода три символа ``` .